# while saving data from data gridview to table getting error:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i am working on vb.net windows form ,I have a data grid view,,i am trying to save data grid values

I am saving data to Two Tables..my Table Names:

```
1->CompanyMaster_tbl
2->DepartmentMaster_tbl
```

I given code in save button like this:

```
Dim CompanyMaster_tbl As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim DepartmentMaster_tbl As DataTable = Nothing

        For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows
            For i As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2

                If gv.Rows(i).Cells("cmpny").Value <> "" Then
                    sqlInsertT1 &= "Insert Into CompanyMaster_tbl(CompanyName) Values ('" & gv.Rows(i).Cells("cmpny").Value & "');"
                    Exetransaction(sqlInsertT1)
                End If
                Ccid = RecordID("Cid", "CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", gv.Rows(i).Cells("cmpny").Value)
            Next

            For Each DepartmentMaster_row As DataRow In DepartmentMaster_tbl.Select(Ccid)
                For j As Integer = 0 To gv.RowCount - 2
                    sqlInsertT2 &= "Insert Into DepartmentMaster_tbl(dtname,dtphone,dtEmail,Cid) Values ('" & gv.Rows(j).Cells("Dpmnt").Value & "','" & gv.Rows(j).Cells("dtphon").Value & "','" & gv.Rows(j).Cells("mail").Value & "'," & Ccid & ");"
                    Exetransaction(sqlInsertT2)
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

while coming to this line   am getting error:

> For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*     why i am getting this error? what is wrong with my code

Comment: Dim CompanyMaster_tbl = Nothing is the problem...

Comment: instead of that what i have to give?

Comment: in such case your `CompanyMaster_tbl` is null and that's why when you do `.Rows` it's throwing null ref exception. You might want to check `CompanyMaster_tbl`

Comment: what i want to check in CompanyMaster_tbl

Comment: Well given what you are doing I'd have expected your table to be pointing at a table in a data set pointed at a connection. Certainly making it Nothing and then trying to use it isn't going to work.

Comment: Sir,,then how i can save data from grid view to multiple tables

Comment: If you all ready have a working grid view pointing at the table, try taking out the two dim statements, depending on the rest of your code which we can't see it might work. If not then you need to get the data tables you are using in the grid views. Either way the dim as nothings are not in anyway useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work in VB.NET (rather in C#) but your code make no sense.

You saying ...

```
Dim CompanyMaster_tbl 
As DataTable = Nothing <-- (here CompanyMaster_tbl set to null)


        For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow 
       In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows <-- you are trying to referencing it.
```

So, it will definitely throw you null reference exception.

Instead of saying ...

```
For Each CompanyMaster_row As DataRow In CompanyMaster_tbl.Rows
```

Why not loop through rows in your gridview and then populate the datatable

```
For Each DataGridViewRow gr In gv.Rows

      If gr.Cells("cmpny").Value <> "" Then
            sqlInsertT1 &= "Insert Into CompanyMaster_tbl(CompanyName) 
            Values ('" & gr.Cells("cmpny").Value & "');"
            Exetransaction(sqlInsertT1)
        End If
        Ccid = RecordID("Cid", "CompanyMaster_tbl", "CompanyName", 
        gr.Cells("cmpny").Value)
    Next
```

Comment: it is oke sir,,,so how i can save data from gridview to mutilpe tables

Comment: The answer already answers this question. Loop through the GridView and insert rows from there, not an uninstantiated DataTable. Further than that, I think you may benefit to understand the differences between your source and destination. Go back to basics a little more.

Comment: @user3106114, as said in my answer, loop through the grid and then just follow your code .. the same way you were inserting data before. see my edit.

Comment: sir but this line showing error "For Each gridviewrow gr In gv.Rows" syntax error

Comment: it's DataGridViewRow and not gridviewrow. so change that line to `For Each DataGridViewRow gr In gv.Rows`. Please help yourself with further syntax errors.

Comment: no sir,,,if i give like this For Each DataGridViewRow gr In gv.Rows,,then also showing syntax error